# Composer: can't find satisfiable version for laravel package illuminate/validation

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-validation

I can't seem to find a satisfiable version for the "illuminate/validation" package. The two appropriate lines I have in my composer.json are:

```
"illuminate/database": "5.8.35",
"illuminate/pagination": "5.8.35"
```

I've tried these commands:

```
composer require illuminate/validation:~3
composer require illuminate/validation:~4
composer require illuminate/validation:~5
composer require illuminate/validation:~6
```

But none of them can find a satisfiable version. They either conflict with illuminate/container which is at version 5.8.36 or symfony/http-foundation which is locked at 3.1.10. Or both.

I don't know that I have much leeway to change the two lines currently in the composer.json, but if it's a non-breaking change, it might be ok.

EDIT:

By request, here is a sample of the "errors", which are really just a bunch of the same:

```
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/validation v4.0.2
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/validation v4.0.1
- Conclusion: remove illuminate/container v5.8.36
- Installation request for illuminate/validation ~4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/validation[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v5.8.36
- illuminate/validation v4.0.0 requires illuminate/container 4.0.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v4.0.0, v5.8.36].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v4.0.1, v5.8.36].
```

Comment: Why are you specifying specific versions of Illuminate sub-components like this at all? [That's not typical](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json).

Comment: It's not a greenfield project - I'm just coming on for a small piece. And it's also not a Laravel project. Eloquent is being bolted onto an existing thing.

Comment: If you can't install dependency x due to conflicts, that usually means you'll have to update other dependencies in order to resolve the conflicts.

Comment: Please share the full and exact error messages

Comment: @NicoHaase - error shared above. It's a whole bunch of the exact same thing, just with every version imaginable listed

Comment: @MrMikkél What if you do `composer require illuminate/validation 5.8.35`? Or `^5.8`?